# Critical point of a Fraction

Tags: calculus

In a problem like, Find the critical point of $$f(x)= \frac{5x}{x-3}$$ What happens to the $5x$ in the numerator? I see that my book has the answer as 3. in order to get 3 I see that I can set $x-3=0$ and add 3 to both sides correct $x-3+3=0+3$ Therefore $x=3$. Is this the correct way to look at this problem?

Comment: As stated, your function is equal to $2$ for every $x$...

Comment: You need to take the derivative and set it equal to zero.

Comment: First of all when you say "your function is equal to 2 for every x," I don't understand that!! thats like me as a web designer talking web design talk to a person who can hardly use a computer. First I think you should try to get a understanding of what I know then speak in terms of my current knowledge. I have no clue what 2 being equal to all x in my function is going to do for me sir. Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would define a "critical point" as the zero-points of the first derivative of your function. Since this functions first derivative has no zero-point, the critical point you search for is probably the point where your function is not defined. This means for your example to find the zero-points of the denominator, because it is "not allowed" to divide by 0. Your posted solution does exactly this and hence is the correct way to look at this problem.

Comment: Hey thanks this make sense, How would I know not to ignore the numerator in a problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the critical points, you have the derivative first.

Your function is $$f(x)= \frac{5x}{x-3}$$

Assuming you know the quotient rule, the derivative will then become $$f'(x) = -\frac{15}{(x-3)^2}$$

Critical points are defined as points where either $f'(x) = 0$ or $f'(x)$ is undefined.

Looking at the derivative, we see that when $$x=3$$

$f'(x)$ is undefined

**You misinterpreted the answer. When it said x =3 was a critical point, you assumed that it came from $f(x)$. In your context, x =3 would be a vertical asymptotic for $f(x).$**

Comment: Meaning at '$$f'(x)= -15/(x-3)^2$$' the derivative of -15 is zero?

Comment: no at x = 3, the derivative is undefined. That is what a critical point is defined as. It is a coordinate where $f'(x)$ is either 0 or undefined.